# Eventos no funcionan en la instancia al extender EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, nodejs, eventos

Estoy intentando hacer una clase que extienda `EventEmitter` y el problema es que no emite ni escucha eventos en la clase ya instanciada, únicamente funciona solo si se usan dentro de la clase.

Acá dejo mi codigo:

***Index.js***:

```javascript
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const element = typeof document === 'undefined' ? null : window.document;

export default class BarcodeScanner extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super()
    this.options = Object.assign({
      latency: 50,
      minLength: 3,
      element,
      endKey: 'Enter',
      validKey: /^\w$/,
      devicePrefix: null
    }, options);
    this.on('code', (code) => {
      console.log(code, e)
    })
    this.initHandler();
  }

  initHandler() {
    this.emit('code', {code:1234556});
  }

}
```

***demo.js***:

```javascript
import BarcodeScanner from './src/index.js'

let scanner = new BarcodeScanner({
  endKey: 'Intro'
});

scanner.emit('code', {code: 1234556})

scanner.on('code', (code) => {
  console.log(code, e)
})
```

Al intentar utilizar `this.on` o `this.emit` dentro de la clase funciona pero solo dentro de la misma clase, en la instancia (`scanner`) no se recibe data.

Al intentar utilizar `scanner.on` o `scanner.emit` en demo.js no funciona, ni dentro ni fuera de la clase.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal? Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolverlo asincronizando la inicialización con `process.nextTick(() => {this.initHandler()});`

Este es mi codigo:

```javascript
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import { events as inputs } from 'gkm';
import _enventHandler from './eventHandler.js'

export default class BarcodeScanner extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(options) {
    super()
    this.options = Object.assign({
      latency: 50,
      minLength: 3,
      endKey: 'Enter',
      validKey: /^\w$/,
      devicePrefix: null
    }, options);
    this._enventHandler = _enventHandler.bind(this, this.options)
    process.nextTick(() => {
      this.initHandler()
    });
  }

  async initHandler() {
    inputs.on('key.pressed', this._enventHandler)
  }

  off() {
    inputs.removeAllListeners('key.pressed',  this._enventHandler)
  }

}
```

Parece que era un problema de sincronia.